# Compiler in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the meaning of Stored procedures are “pre compile”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265503/what-is-the-meaning-of-stored-procedures-are-pre-compile)

I read that stored procedures in SQL Server are compiled before they are executed. AFAIK, a compiler is used to translating high-level language into machine language or some kind of intermediate language (such as .NET IL code). So I am wondering what does SQL Server compiler do? What is a stored procedure compiled into?

Thanks.

Comment: you have the word 'wikipedia' in your username, but show a distinct lack of interest in using said resource! :)

Answer (score 2):

Compiling a query is the process of creating an Execution Plan. Compiled execution plans are cached and re-used every time a query executes.